# Failed to initialize a pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

```
int array[2] = {1, 1};
int (*pointer_array)[2] = {NULL, NULL};
```

The first line can be correctly compiled but not the second one? Why?

GCC compiler will pop up a warning, `excess elements in scalar initializer`.

How to initialize a pointer array in C?

**EDITED**

I declared a pointer array in a wrong way.

It should be like this:

```
int *pointer_array[2] = {NULL, NULL};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
int (*pointer_array)[2]=(int[]){1,2};
```

This is pointer to array of `int` .I don't know you want pointer to array of `int` or array of pointers.

To declare as array of pointer you need to do this -

```
int *pointer_array[2];
```

Comment: So sorry for that, I misunderstood the usage of declaring a pointer array. The last line is what I really need. :-)

Comment: @KevinDong  Well , no problem .It happens :)

Comment: Considering that he's assigning to `{NULL, NULL}`, I think it's pretty clear that he wants an array of pointers to `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array of int of length 5 e.g.

```
int x[5];
```

Then you can do `a = &x;`

```
 int x[5] = {1};
 int (*a)[5] = &x;
```

To access elements of array you: `(*a)[i]` (`== (*(&x))[i]== (*&x)[i] == x[i]`) parenthesis needed because precedence of `[]` operator is higher then `*`. (one common mistake can be doing `*a[i]` to access elements of array).

Understand what you asked in question is a compilation time error:

```
int (*a)[3] = {11, 2, 3, 5, 6};
```

It is not correct and a type mismatch too, because `{11,2,3,5,6}` can be assigned to `int a[5];` and you are assigning to `int (*a)[3]`.

Additionally,

You can do something like for one dimensional:

```
int *why = (int[2]) {1,2};
```

Similarly, for two dimensional try this(thanks @caf):

```
int (*a)[5] = (int [][5]){ { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } , { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };
```